# Why do I need to use curly brackets for the route parameter?

Tags: javascript

I am using react navigation v5 and I am pushing a parameter from one screen to another. I made it work, but I cannot understand, why I need to use the curly brackets there. And where would I add the props parameter?

```
1 screen
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { nav.navigate('userProfile', { userId: 1 }) }} >

2 screen
const userProfile = ({ route }) => {
    const { id } = route.params;
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{id}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

As I said it is working as this, but usually I have something like

```
const userProfile = (props) =>
```

How would I add props to the 2 screen? And why do I need to use the curly brackets and how do I know if I can add it as a parameter like props or if I need to use the brackets.

Thanks!

Update: I found out, that it is also working with props.route.params.id. I am very confused now.

Comment: `({ route }) => { ... ` is simply destructuring the route property out of `props`. This isn't a react question, it's a question about [JS object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring)

Answer (score 2):

This is called **Destructuring** in javascript...

here you're extracting `route` out of `userProfile` `props`

```
const userProfile = ({ route }) => {
```

which is equivalent to

```
const userProfile = (props) => {
  const route = props.route;
};
```

==

```
const userProfile = (props) => {
  const { route } = props;
};
```

Comment: Technically it's not equivalent to using `const route = ...`. Destructuring a parameter will not declare it as const by default

Comment: Ah, so that explains why props.route.params.id, is working as well. Why would I use this instead of just props? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Sylber Yes, it's just a shorthand syntax for extracting specific properties off of an object into named local variables. The reason you do it is for convenience, more than anything. Neither way is "more proper"

Comment: @Sylber personal-preference ... just to save a line of code...

Comment: Hey @mhodges I'm just trying to clarify the idea here ..

Comment: Please change `const route = props.route` to `let` or `var` so I can upvote this answer for correctness